# How to set full screen on <WebView /> when embed youtube url?

Tags: react-native

The platform is Android.  I use  to embed youtube video.

```
  <View style={{ height: 240 }}>
    <WebView
    style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
    scalesPageToFit={true}
        source={{uri: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId[0]}?rel=0&autoplay=0&controls=1&showinfo=0`}}
    />
  </View>
```

I can see the zoom in button but it can't be clicked.

[image]

I try to add `scalesPageToFit={true}` on  is still not working.

Is it possible to zoom in when using  with embed youtube url ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have search and find the props `allowsFullscreenVideo={true}` set it true that enables fullscreen into the WebView.

Please check the final code.

```
<WebView
    source={{uri: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId[0]}?rel=0&autoplay=0&controls=1&showinfo=0`}}
    style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
    allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
    scalesPageToFit={true}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-youtube](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube).

Comment: I know it, but I get the issue now https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube/issues/276, so I try to use <WebView /> for Android.

Comment: Then you can use [react-native-orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation) and set the component to landscape. Then set the height and width of web view to screen size by using [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions). Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to embed your video in an iFrame with property.

```js
allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
```

Give iFrame the above mentioned property and for your information allowfullscreen="true" is a wrong input.